# JSF ui:insert within an <li tag

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have JSF template which looks as follows:

```
<li> some text 1 </li>
...
<li> some text 100</li>
```

Now I want to set the class-attribute of this element in a derived file. Therefore I tried to add an `ui:insert` tag:

```
<li <ui:insert name="nav.home" /> >

However this throws an exception at startup:
javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /layout.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 43]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: why don't you put the whole <li>-tag in the <ui:define> section? You could pass some values through, so you can use these as class-attributes.

Comment: because I just want to set the class attribute nothing else

Comment: I think <ui:insert> isn't what you are looking for. You should store the class-attributes in a bean. The insert-tag is for a block of code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store these values in a (session-scoped) bean.

```
@ManagedBean(name="myBean")
@SessionScoped

public class myJSFBean {

private String attribute;

public String getAttribute() {}

}
```

If you need different class-attributes, you can use some kind of list instead of a string in your backing bean.

To get the value, you can simply use:

```
<li attributeXY=#{myBean.attribute}></li>
```

If you need to define attributeXY too, I'd try to print the whole html in javascript.